# What will detach objects implicitly from a SQLAlchemy session?

Tags: sqlalchemy

We have a situation in which, at some point in our code, we are seeing certain objects as detached, but we don't explicitly detach the objects ourselves. What SQLAlchemy methods/actions can cause objects to become detached? Maybe closing a session or something similar?

Note: I've read the SQLAlchemy documentation, which does cover re-attaching objects to sessions, but is relatively more scant on what actually can detach instances implicitly.

Answer (score 3):

session.close() will detach all objects.   A rollback as noted will detach those objects that were INSERTed in the rolled-back transaction as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the main one would be if you were to "rollback" a session. As [the docs say](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#rolling-back):

> Objects which were initially in the pending state when they were added
>   to the Session within the lifespan of the transaction are expunged,
>   corresponding to their INSERT statement being rolled back. The state
>   of their attributes remains unchanged.